# Drunk in German

Tags: meaning

My dictionary (print and online) gave me *betrunken*, which doesn't ring a bell with my childish trips to the Steirmark.  Seem to remember something like *gesauffen* or the like?  Which is correct and/or is there a regional preference.

I did try researching it...

Comment: I'm sure your dictionary of choice gave you more than one translation. If it doesn't: choose another. https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/drunk

Comment: @planetmaker: dictionaries are not a great help if someone looks for terms that are commonly used in a small region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was born in Graz and grew up in Styria. Dialect and colloquial speech terms are these (in brackets a translation into standard German):

- **augsoffn** (angesoffen)
  This is the most common term used in Styria. The *g* belongs to *gsoffn* (gesoffen), so there is a tiny break between *au* and *gsoffn.*  In combination with the *s* the word sounds like *au-xoffn.* The prefix *au-* (an-) is a diphthong where both vowels have a touch of an o-sound in them. Note, that the last syllable (ffn) has no vowel but a vocalized *n* instead.
- **bsoffn** (besoffen)
  Also possible in Styria, but less frequently used as *augsoffn*
- **fett** or also **vui fett** (fett; voll fett)
  The adjective *fett* is commonly used in all Bavarian dialects as a synonym for being drunk. Sorry, I can't explain why *fett* is used this way.
- **zua** or also **vui zua** (zu; voll zu)
  Very similar to *fett.* The word *zu* (englisch: closed) is used because it seems as if the connection between the real outside world and the inside world of the drunk is closed.
- **autschechat** (angetscherchert)
  The verb tschechern [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tschechern), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tschechern), [usage in an Austrian magazine](https://www.gusto.at/home/sogar-gleichzeitiges-gelage-wien-new-york-135028), [invitation to event from university Vienna](https://kalender.univie.ac.at/einzelansicht/?tx_univieevents_pi1%5Bid%5D=30097) is in the east of Austria an often used term for drinking much alcohol. I think it is not very common elsewhere. - About *au-* see *augsoffen.*
- **rauschi, rauschig** (rauschig)
  The German noun *der Rausch* names the mental state in which a person is, that consumed alcohol or drugs. So, technically the adjective *rauschig* means: being drunk or being on drugs. But in fact it is most often used when a person is drunk.

Comment: Thanks, man.  It's hard!  My snippets of memory can be mistaken.  But other times, they are valid and there is just a difference from Austria to Germany.  Like what the heck is gucken or a Treppe?  Aber kleine Buhrli versteh ich.  And I spent time in very rural (walk up the hill to church) mountains of Styria, and in Wein...And it all gets vermudelt.  and just got a very mixed up casual use of the language...like I can chat with children or in bars...but not in office settings or technical discussions.  But I want to learn some erwachsene words now.  Not just Eierschrummisuchen und Kuheholen.

Comment: (Not entirely a Witz), but how does the "Gestern haben wir gesoffen; Heute sindt wir krank" song come into it?  Is that a German song?  Austrian?  Styrian?

Comment: @Amiguest: About "Gestern haben wir gesoffen; Heute sind wir krank": I didn't know this song, but when I goggled for it I found a German soldier's song from 1910: https://www.volksliederarchiv.de/ist-das-nicht-die-hobelbank/ It is a vulgar erotic song. The verb *hobeln* (to plane wood) is also a synonym for having sex.

Comment: About "Wein..." There are many vilages in Styria that contain "Wein" in their name. I was born in Graz, but grew up in *Wein*itzen northeast of Graz, and north of Graz is Grat*wein* and some vilages with very similar names: *Wein*zödl, *Wein*zöttl and *Wein*zettl. There is also *Wein*berg and *Wein*burg in Styria. The *Wein*ebene is a region at the border to Carinthia. In the south-east of Styria is *Wein*leiten.

Comment: I meant Wien and Wienerisch.  All muddled.

Comment: About *Eierschrummisuchen:* You probably mean *Eierschwammerlsuchen.* This compound word is made from *Eierschwammerl* and *suchen.* *Suchen* just means to search. *Schwammerl* is the Austrian word for an eatable mushroom (Another one is *Pilz* which is also in use in Germany, but a *Pilz* can be any fungus, while *Schwammerl* is something that you can eat.) And *Eierschwammerl* literally means *egg-mushroom.* Another term for the same mushroom is *Recherl.* Both, *Recherl* and *Eierschwammerl* are only used in regions where bavarian dialects are spoken. outside this area its *Pfifferling.*

Comment: And yeah, that sounds like the song, but I don't remember it being something grandmothers wouldn't sing.  But I sort of have multiple songs mixed in my head, I think.  "Oh du lieber Augistin".  And then "heute sindt wir krank".  And probably also "Ist das nicht ein volleyball." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijmUV3JH3L8

Answer (score 3):

In Styrian, it's *gsoff'n sei*.

In Standard German that would be *gesoffen sein* but it means a different thing: the thing drunk is *gesoffen* but not the person who did it. Standard German uses ***be**soffen sein* for the latter.

---

**CALL FOR ACTION**

Let's reintroduce the Partizip II ***bezecht*** into contemporary German. It just sounds so much more German. As if someone wrote a police report on it.

Comment: Thanks...that's my dim memory!  (I didn't at all understand the action call, but no worries.)

Comment: **This answer is wrong.** I am a native of Styria. The participle *gsoffen* is used in Styria only verbally (as a verb), but not adjectivally. Correct (usage as verb): *»I hob gestern zfüh gsoffn.«* (Ich habe gestern zu viel gesoffen.) Wrong (usage as adjective): *»I bin **g**soffn.«* (Ich bin **g**esoffen.) Correct: *»I bin **b**soffn«* (Ich bin **b**esoffen.)

Comment: I moved the greenie.  I still love you though, Janka.  ;-)  Srsly, mad thanks for other answers and comments!

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Okay.

Answer (score 2):

- besoffen (harsh expression)
- betrunken (less harsh)
- blau
- abgefüllt (strong)
- dicht, hacke dicht (strong)
- beschwipst (minor issue)
- angeheitert (minor, too)
- im Zustand akuter Alkoholintoxikation (medical jargon)
- …

Comment: Thank you.  Hmm...maybe I need to do some theory to practice immersion training.  Activity and speaking together.  ;-)